# NodeJS: Save menu order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm having some trouble saving my menu order in NodeJS with Mongoose.

First off I loop out my menu structure via Jade:

```
form(method='post', action='/admin/pages/order')
    ul
        each page in pages
            li
                input(type='number', name='order', value= page.order)
                |  - 
                a(href='/admin/pages/edit/' + page._id)= page.title
                |  - 
                a(href='/admin/pages/delete/' + page._id) Delete page

    button Save order
```

page.order is describing the page's current order. Ie. Frontpage 10, About 20, Contact 30 etc. And if I want another order, I should be able to move Frontpage to 25 which will place it between About and Contact, but whenever I save. The order is messed up.

Maybe I'm missing some code below or doing something wrong?

And here is my save post:

```
var Page = require('../models/page');

app.post('/admin/pages/order', function(req, res) {
    var pageOrder = req.body.order;
    var counter = [];

    Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) {
        pages.forEach(function(page, index) {
            counter.push(true);

            page.order = 0;
            page.save();

            if (counter.length === pages.length) {
                counter = [];
                var count = 1;

                Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) {
                    pages.forEach(function(page, index) {
                        counter.push(true);

                        page.order = 10 * count++;
                        page.save();

                        if (counter.length === pages.length) {
                            res.redirect('/admin/pages');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Just say if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about using `async` and doing the first sort in memory rather than going to the database twice. You can try this (I haven't tested it). It uses [Underscore](https://www.npmjs.org/package/underscore) to do the sorting.

```
_ = require("underscore");
async = require("async");

// ...

var newPageOrders = req.body.order;

// Get the pages in their original order
Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) {
  if (err) return res.send(err);

  // Set the order on the pages to the new order
  pages.forEach(function (page, index) {
    page.order = newPageOrders[index];
  });

  // Use the Underscore library to sort the list of pages by its new ordering
  pages = _.sortBy(pages, 'order');

  // Now that we've sorted the pages, normalize the order numbers
  pages.forEach(function (page, index) {
    page.order = index*10
  });

  // Save all of the pages
  async.forEach(pages, function (page, callback) {
    // Save the page. Pass in the callback which async provides us with,
    // so that async knows when the page is saved
    page.save(callback);
  }, function (err) {
    // This function is only called once all of the pages are saved
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.redirect('/admin/pages');
  });
});
```

Comment: I will accept this as an correct answer, well yes because this is exactly what I want - so many thanks sir :). But am I able to do this without underscore package? Say Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) { .... }); and sort it that way again?

Comment: but then I will be reaching into my record again. Hmm :)

Comment: You could try using the [native sort method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) on arrays, passing in a comparator function like `function(pageA, pageB) {return pageA.order - pageB.order;}`

Comment: Thanks alot. You have been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

It is too hard to understand what you want, below is a brief description of what do I understand.

```
//You have following `pages` records : 
{
title : 'Frontpage'
order:10
}
,
{
title : 'About'
order:20
}
,
{
title : 'Contact'
order:30
}
```

And now you want to `change/modify/update` the `order` of some page (ie. Frontpage to 25).

If I understand you correctly then I would advise you to use a different route for handling those `updates`.

```
/*
What the following handler does is :
Whenever you attempt to change the page order, first of all it tries to get one with the same order and assign its order to the page's order that is going to be updated. (I hope it is clear enough)
*/
app.put('/admin/pages/:pageId/order', function(req, res) {

Page.findOne({order:req.body.order}, function(err, doc){

       Page.findById(req.params.pageId, function(err, page) {
          var pageOrder = page.order;
          page.order = req.body.order;
          page.save();

          if(doc) {
           doc.order = pageOrder;
           doc.save();
          }
       });
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the explantion. It is almost what I want to do.Execpt I want to update all my pages at once as I hit 'Save order' with a potential new order for all of them. As my req.body.order will contain a array for all of my pages current order. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. By doing this instead:

```
app.post('/admin/pages/order', function(req, res) {
    var pageOrder = req.body.order;
    var counter = [];
    var count = 1;

    Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) {
        pages.forEach(function(page, index) {
            counter.push(true);

            Page.findOneAndUpdate({order: page.order}, {order: pageOrder[index]}, true, function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
            });

            if (counter.length === pages.length) {
                counter = [];

                Page.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'order' : 1 } }, function(err, pages) {
                    pages.forEach(function(page, index) {
                        counter.push(true);

                        page.order = count++ * 10;
                        page.save();

                        if (counter.length === pages.length) {
                            res.redirect('/admin/pages');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I had to use the findOneAndUpdate in order to get a fresh list of my menu. So I could clean up the order with count++ * 10 and then save it to the database.

Is this the smartest way of doing this? And page.save() doesnt update the database right away?

Comment: page.save is an async function - you can call it with a callback and it will be called when the model is saved (or if there's an error, it will be the first argument to the callback). I think a smarter way to do this is to manually sort the list in memory, then do the count++*10 clean-up thing, rather than pushing it to the DB, pulling it back sorted, then pushing it back with the count++*10 cleanup.

Comment: Alright fair enough. Well as you say: If it aint broke, dont fix it:). But as I'm in the learning curve of Node etc I would really love to learn how to do this properly. Could I get you to try to do this with async and in memory? If it aint to much to ask. I tried with async but never got close solving this with that. Thanks in advance

Comment: By "with async" you mean the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) package?